# Android date picker not rendering in preview

Tags: android, android-activity, datepicker

I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2, and inserted the DatePicker control to my activity.  It seems to work pretty well during runtime, but it has consistently resulted in Rendering Problems in the preview, which makes it difficult to design the Activity.  I didn't see any posts on this issue, but was wondering if anyone has come across this.  I could post the xml, but I don't think it will help, as it seems pretty clean.

Thank you!

Here's the message I get:

ERROR RESOURCE RELATED

Rendering Problems

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException   
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:490)   
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:93)




    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.04">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Reminder (days ahead): "
            android:id="@+id/EditSpecialDay_textDate" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.04">

        <DatePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight=".04" />
    </TableRow>



</LinearLayout>
```

As requested here's the stack (does this help?)

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:490)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:93)
        at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:2484)
        at android.widget.YearPickerView$YearAdapter.getView(YearPickerView.java:132)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.TableRow.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableRow.java:247)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1083)
        at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:114)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:626)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:526)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:334)
        at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:688)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:677)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:677)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:815)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:646)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:584)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
        at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Hi...once clean & build the project (For studio not sure bt i guess its Make project option) and still if its not working thn can you pls share code what u hve dne in xml and all

Comment: The clean and build did not work -anyhow, I've done this many times while having this issue.  I pasted the last bit of xml which includes the datepicker

Comment: hi i hve checked with my AD studio its working fine with you code .. rendering is also fine .. can u pls full log cat what u r getting  ?

Comment: Note that I did not include the entire xml just to keep the post brief.  So, I'm not sure if the update in your answer changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

once check the below posted code

For Horizontally view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.04">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Reminder (days ahead): "
            android:id="@+id/EditSpecialDay_textDate" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.04">

        <DatePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>


</LinearLayout>
```

For vertically view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.04">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Reminder (days ahead): "
            android:id="@+id/EditSpecialDay_textDate" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.04">

        <DatePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             />
    </TableRow>


</LinearLayout>
```

Based on the xml which u posted in question what can be possible causes is like API level wise rending issue once change the api level from graphical preview.

XML design is not proper like in `TableRow` weight is given thn height and width should be `0dp` so once check the code which i shared it may help.

Any one you can use horizontally or vertically